# How to get ID of current record?

Tags: cakephp

Another CakePHP framework question...

How can I get the ID of the current record?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Basically if you wondering how to get ID of the record after the save action it's very easy.

```
if($this->MyModel->save($this->data)){
    //the id is here
    echo $this->MyModel->id;
}
```

HTH

Comment: tnx, but i don't need it after the save.

i need to get ID there when i open details of some record, in edit or view layout.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i got it!

it's

```
echo $modelName['ModelName']['id'];
```

tnx anw!

Comment: doesn't this only work if the $modelName contains the id field? ( editing record, not saving a new one )..